# Why the const value can be changed in Chrome's Sources tab's Scope section?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In JS, you cannot reassign a value to a `const` declaration. But when you run the code, at that time you can change the `const` value in Chrome's Source's tab's Scope section.

Why is this allowed? Can anyone please explain the concept that is being used here?

As shown in the below screenshot, I defined `foo` with value 10 but then was able to change the value to 20 in **Scope** section

[image]

Comment: Is there a useful reason a debugger *shouldn’t* be able to do that? Because being able to do it is useful.

Comment: I am not saying that browsers should not do it. My question how the whole thing happens? Why the debugger allows the things, that the language doesn't allow?

Comment: It’s a restriction imposed on JavaScript code by the engine, and not imposed on the debugger.

Comment: Debugger can do a lot of things that aren't allowed by the language.

Comment: @newbie Because a debugger isn't bound by the rules of the language. It lets you directly interact with the JS execution process in the engine (most prominently, pausing and resuming it arbitrarily).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply. Just one more thing, is there any other way (other than using debugger) to change the variable values like above in the running JS code?

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found this question because I had tried to set the value of a `const` in the console, which isn't allowed. I know this isn't a direct answer, but may help if you find this idea with the need to edit a value.

I had actually never realized you **could** edit values in the dev tools because they make it so finicky to do so.

Discovered the trick is to click on the property name and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
If you are trying to set something `null` or `undefined` you must type it in. Don't be tempted to hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> because it will look like it's been deleted but it will just come back again.